# Windows macro name clash

Tags: c++, visual-studio, autocomplete, macros

I'm working on a line graph project using ImGui api for Windows with directx9. However I'm having trouble with autocompletion upon declaring/defining/calling methods on which `<windows.h>` has macros defined.

LineChart.h
[image: LineChart.h]

LineChart.cpp

[image: LineChart.cpp]

How to workaround this?

Comment: Is "LineChart.h" your code or 3rd party library?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm no, it's not.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thanks

Comment: The cleanest way would be to not include <windows.h>. Do you use a lot from it?

Comment: @BerndBaumanns not much, but I'm forced to use  `GetWindowRect` to retrieve the win32 window size (in case of user re-sizing) and manually resize the ImGui api windows/labels. And also `GetWindowPlacement` to verify whether the window is minimized/maximized as a maximized Windows window does not display left/right/bottom borders.